# Matplotlib error: variadic keyword parameters cannot have default values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the resulting learning curves from a neural network and came across this error:

> **ValueError**: variadic keyword parameters cannot have default values

The it seems to be coming from matplotlib as this is what I added when I got the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(8,3))
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

I'm still learning python so if you need more information let me know.

If anyone can point me in the right direction please do!

Comment: `history.history` is not defined

Comment: Please give example of your dataframe. Otherwise it's impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm the first couple lines of the error message says something along the lines of:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-a84c0541e888> in <module>

----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

If so matplotlib is part of the issue (not the DataFrame object). Currently troubleshooting a similar issue, I'll update once I have figured out the solution.

Have you tried reinstalling the library or updating?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    pip install matplotlib --user
```

Then import matplotlib again, it should work.